Prevent Spyder editor from opening on startup
Is there any way to prevent the editor from opening when Spyder starts?
This Q&A is about opening files on startup if those files were open when Spyder was last closed.  In my case, usually have the editor closed when I quit Spyder.
This GitHub issue is about project-specific files that are kept open.  I am not working in the context of a defined project, and I don't want any files remembered.

You mean you want spyder to open without showing the editor panel right away?

Yes, that's it.

most panes, if you close them and then you close spyder, will not show up again when you reopen spyder. Editor seems to be an exception. Is this what you mean?

Yes!  As it turns out, however, there is another oddity that makes it necessary to keep the code editor open.  Issuing runfile doesn't always run the latest file.  So there is some caching of source code.  Only if I have the editor open to the file and click in the editor to change focus to it, only then does the source code in the editor update.  If the editor is not open, then sometimes, the (presumably) cached code runs instead of the latest code in the file.
